# External tools for a RAD Studio / C++ / Windows project? (How to get PDB from RAD Studio and/or what are other options?)

Tags: profiling, c++builder, pdb-files, rad-studio

I have a project of a 64-bit Windows application in Rad Studio 11 (pre-existing project, not my choice, moving to another toolchain is not an option). The language is C++ (C++17). So far, I've been unable to find and use a tool for either code coverage analysis, memory monitoring or performance profiling. To avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I'm asking a rather broad question:

### What are my options for external tools with RAD Studio?

Current RAD studio uses a "Clang-enhanced C++ compiler" `bcc64` based on [Clang 5.0](https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/index.html) and a linker `ilink64` which seems to be their own software - [doc1](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/C%2B%2B_Linker), [doc2](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_ILINK32_and_ILINK64_on_the_Command_Line). Additional options provided to `bcc64` seem to be limited to the `-cc1` Clang subset: `-fcoverage-mapping` is recognized but `-fprofile-instr-generate` is not (or I'm missing a setting that would allow it, as is the possibility for all my examples in this post).

Using tools described in Clang documentation seems to require either providing compiler options that get rejected by `bcc64` or providing linker options that simply don't exist for `ilink64`. So I think that my best bet would be using third-party software like OpenCppCoverage / Dr. Memory / Very Sleepy / etc. However, all such software for Windows seemingly expects debug information as a separate `.pdb` file. And I can't squeeze it from `ilink64`: `bcc64` accepts `-gcodeview` (but not `-g`) but `ilink64` seemingly doesn't have an option to generate `.pdb` at all. It can produce `.tds` files which may be possible to convert to `.pdb`... but only for 32-bit applications, for 64-bit this option does nothing.

An idea to try and use another linker doen't look productive since the project uses Borland .bpl components - unless someone knows how to make this work.

Resources on RAD studio are (or at least *feel*) very scarce: [Embarcadero community site](https://community.embarcadero.com/index.php) has news from late 2018 on the front page, their "new developers community" link redirects to [the blogs page](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/) with articles like "how `std::thread` works" and their [collection of "third party community sites"](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/community/) has links to the `c++builder` tag on StackOverflow and [one mostly-dead forum](https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/41-general-help/) on the C++ side of things. I didn't find answers to my questions on any of those.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*"

Comment: [What’s Coming for C++Builder: An Amazing Preview](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/whats-coming-for-cbuilder-an-amazing-preview/): "*... the Clang upgrade is planned not to be an upgrade of our existing compiler with all extra material, but an upgrade of the core key architecture of our compiler. This means we plan to adopt a more platform-standard approach: to emit COFF object files (the ‘native’ or by-convention Windows format); **use the PDB format for debugging; use the LLVM linker not ilink;** ... and we can re-use open source tools and projects, like the LLVM linker...*"